# WebView selector drawable

Tags: android, android-webview

how can I change the focus color/drawable in WebView via Java or XML, that is visible on screen below (the orange thing around href)?

[image: focus on WebView]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't do that. This is the default focus style installed on the phone.
this can only be modified by the website itself using css styling.

Comment: I was thinking the same, but I'll leave it open for few hours, maybe someone will figure out how to do that.

Comment: I not sure that we can inject / overwrite the CSS or not